# How to refresh the MANIFEST.MF file in IntelliJ module?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have added more dependencies to my module. However, the jar artifact does not seem to be aware of it. Do I have to delete and recreate the jar artifact in order for the new dependencies to be included in the manifest and in the jar?

Thanks.